# What is the line connecting the plane and the worker

Tags: commercial-aviation

In the attached picture the attendant is walking along beside the plane as it taxi's. She is clearly holding a line attached to the plane. What is the line for?[image: tarmac worker]

Comment: It is a leash.  She is taking the airplane for a walk.